How to limit the scope of an authorized user in an SSH principals file using a FQDN?
I've been using the SSH AuthorizedPrincipalsFile feature for quite some time and it works fine, but I've discovered recently that it is possible to limit the provenance of a user using the "from=" keyword in the principals file.
However, the problem is that as soon as I add that keyword with an FQDN matching the one used as principals when signing the host key of the source, I cannot login anymore. For instance:

local signed host key:
ssh_host_ed25519_key-cert.pub:
        Type: ...
        Public key: ...
        Signing CA: ...
        Key ID: "hostname.example.com"
        Serial: 0
        Valid: from 2024-05-02T17:06:00 to 2025-05-01T17:07:48
        Principals: 
                hostname.example.com


local signed user key:
id_ed25519-cert.pub:
        Type: ...
        Public key: ...
        Signing CA: ...
        Key ID: "hostname.example.com"
        Serial: 0
        Valid: from 2024-05-02T17:18:00 to 2025-05-01T17:19:47
        Principals: 
                user


on the remote host user_principals:
from="hostname.example.com" user


on the remote host /etc/hosts:
<ipv6_address> hostname.example.com




If I ssh as user from the local host hostname.example.com into the remote host, it fails.
If I remove the from="hostname.example.com" keyword from the remote principals file, the login succeeds.
If I replace the from="hostname.example.com" keyword by from="*.example.com", the login fails.
If I replace the from="hostname.example.com" keyword by from="<ipv6_address>"  where <ipv6_address> is the actual local hostname ipv6 address, the login succeeds.

Has anyone been actually able to implement this with a from="FQDN" or is this an SSH server bug?
Environment:

local host:

Ubuntu noble
openssh-client: 1:9.6p1-3ubuntu13


remote host:

Ubuntu lunar
openssh-server: 1:9.0p1-1ubuntu8.7



